# .Net Dll appears smaller after Compilation

Tags: c#, .net, dll, msbuild

I am actually new to Decompiling & Compiling Dlls & Executables. I recently Decompiled a .Net Dll using .Net Reflector 9. The Dll had an initial size of 245 KB.
I then planned to recompile the Dll using he latest version of MSBuild i.e 14. I didn't make any changes in the .cs files except for one line in the MyProject.csproj i.e

```
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
**<Reference Include="System.xml" />**
```

Since it gave me repeated errors

The command I used was as following:

```
MSBuild /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x86;Outdir=F:\bin\Release\ F:\MyProject.csproj
```

Although the build was successful the compiled Dll had a very small size that of 34 KB. Why is that so? Is there something major missing?

Comment: The original file probably had symbols, source, map while new file just has executable code.

Comment: So it that .Net Reflector wasnt able to decompile the dll correctly or the exported source code..

Comment: Yes.  The decompile was probably correct, just without source the symbols (variable names)  were not correct.

Comment: I guess you are right,, The Compiler gave me these warning 

`MyFolder\clsGenerate.cs(179,58): warning CS0219: The variable 'num3' is assigned but its value is never used [F:\MyFolder\MyProject.csproj]`

Comment: `MyFolder\clsGenerate.cs(434,50): warning CS0219: The variable 'num3' is assigned but its value is never used [F:\MyFolder\MyProject.csproj]`

Comment: `MyFolder\clsGenerate.cs(14,24): warning CS0414: The field 'clsGenerate.connection' is assigned but its value is never used [F:\MyFolder\MyProject.csproj]`

Comment: That is pretty typical for decompiled code. The decompiler creates additional variables here and there to create valid source code. Happens mostly in case the compiler of the original code did some optimizations. Just a idea: Does your new DLL maybe lack some resources embedded in the original one. Maybe the decompiler only extracted the source code, but not the resources.

Comment: Which would then be the best decompiler ?? Suppose I have a Dll but loose its source code, is it that I wont be able to get the source code

Comment: In .Net Reflector the Assembly System.Data gets decompiled with Resources but by Dll Dosent

Answer (score -2):

May be you need something like this:
`<Content Include="System.xml">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>`
instead of
`<Reference Include="System.xml" />`

Comment: Nobody should ever require to copy DLLs of the .NET Framework to anywhere.

Comment: I mean that System.xml is not a System.Xml.dll but just xml file.